# Why does for-range behaves differently depending on the slice struct size?

Tags: go

I was playing around with this code

main_var.go

```
package main

func main() {
    const size = 1000000

    slice := make([]SomeStruct, size)
    for _, s := range slice { // line 7
        _ = s
    }

}
```

type_small.go

```
package main

type SomeStruct struct {
    ID0 int64
    ID1 int64
    ID2 int64
    ID3 int64
    ID4 int64
    ID5 int64
    ID6 int64
    ID7 int64
    ID8 int64
}
```

I noted that if I added another 64 bit int64 `ID9` (total of 10 * 8 byte = 80 byte) to the struct, the for-loop becomes slower.

If I compared the assembly, it added instruction to copy the element

```
// with 9 int64 (72 bytes)
    0x001d 00029 (main_var.go:6)    LEAQ    type."".SomeStruct(SB), AX
    0x0024 00036 (main_var.go:6)    MOVQ    AX, (SP)
    0x0028 00040 (main_var.go:6)    MOVQ    $1000000, 8(SP)
    0x0031 00049 (main_var.go:6)    MOVQ    $1000000, 16(SP)
    0x003a 00058 (main_var.go:6)    CALL    runtime.makeslice(SB)
    0x003f 00063 (main_var.go:6)    XORL    AX, AX
    0x0041 00065 (main_var.go:7)    INCQ    AX
    0x0044 00068 (main_var.go:7)    CMPQ    AX, $1000000
    0x004a 00074 (main_var.go:7)    JLT    65
    0x004c 00076 (main_var.go:7)    MOVQ    32(SP), BP
    0x0051 00081 (main_var.go:7)    ADDQ    $40, SP
    0x0055 00085 (main_var.go:7)    RET
    0x0056 00086 (main_var.go:7)    NOP
    0x0056 00086 (main_var.go:3)    CALL    runtime.morestack_noctxt(SB)
    0x005b 00091 (main_var.go:3)    JMP    0

// with 10 int64 (80 bytes), it added DUFFCOPY instruction
    0x001d 00029 (main_var.go:6)    LEAQ    type."".SomeStruct(SB), AX
    0x0024 00036 (main_var.go:6)    MOVQ    AX, (SP)
    0x0028 00040 (main_var.go:6)    MOVQ    $1000000, 8(SP)
    0x0031 00049 (main_var.go:6)    MOVQ    $1000000, 16(SP)
    0x003a 00058 (main_var.go:6)    CALL    runtime.makeslice(SB)
    0x003f 00063 (main_var.go:6)    MOVQ    24(SP), AX
    0x0044 00068 (main_var.go:6)    XORL    CX, CX
    0x0046 00070 (main_var.go:7)    JMP    76
    0x0048 00072 (main_var.go:7)    ADDQ    $80, AX
    0x004c 00076 (main_var.go:7)    LEAQ    ""..autotmp_7+32(SP), DI
    0x0051 00081 (main_var.go:7)    MOVQ    AX, SI
    0x0054 00084 (main_var.go:7)    DUFFCOPY    $826 # <-- copy the element
    0x0067 00103 (main_var.go:7)    INCQ    CX
    0x006a 00106 (main_var.go:7)    CMPQ    CX, $1000000
    0x0071 00113 (main_var.go:7)    JLT    72
    0x0073 00115 (main_var.go:7)    MOVQ    112(SP), BP
    0x0078 00120 (main_var.go:7)    ADDQ    $120, SP
    0x007c 00124 (main_var.go:7)    RET
    0x007d 00125 (main_var.go:7)    NOP
    0x007d 00125 (main_var.go:3)    CALL    runtime.morestack_noctxt(SB)
    0x0082 00130 (main_var.go:3)    JMP    0
```

I am wondering why the different behavior for larger struct (> 80 bytes) even though in both cases the element of the slice is not being used.

Comment: I also wonder why the compiler doesn't elide the whole loop. It seems to be smart enough to avoid the copy in the first case (if you pay attention, it only loops).

Comment: My first thought was/is memory alignment and padding much like this article: https://medium.com/@sebassegros/golang-dealing-with-maligned-structs-9b77bacf4b97

Comment: To me it just seems like a missed optimization: when an object would be big enough to require a duff copy (https://golang.org/src/runtime/mkduff.go) it doesn't check if the value is actually used and inserts the copy nonetheless. I'm guessing you just hit the inflection point it uses to decide if it is big or small.

Comment: @lucidquiet, I thought of something similar, but focused on cache, but in both cases there should be split cache lines (both are >64 bytes per element, the line size for most x86 processors). The fact the first loop does nothing is the key to the issue.

Comment: i do find this rewrite condition https://golang.org/src/cmd/compile/internal/ssa/rewriteAMD64.go#L54447. But not sure if that's is the case. If I understand this is that DUFFCOPY is an optimization of MOVE for a certain size. But indeed why the first one doesn't generate any copy the first place is very intriguing

Comment: It's pretty clearly a missed optimization, as @Oppen says. Probably what is happening is that the copy elision (which happens for the 72 byte struct) got wrecked by the DUFFCOPY insertion (which happens for the 80 byte struct), but precisely why that happened is very dependent on compiler internals. I'd bet anyone who's intimately familiar with this particular compiler's dead-variable elimination could tell you what happened, and what sort of major overhaul might be required to fix it and why they haven't already. :-)

Comment: The reason why it's not fixed is probably that this case is, I think, quite unlikely in the wild unless made by mistake. I may take a look to the compiler at some point out of curiosity, but I doubt I understand much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that this is because of SSA optimization. 
More explicitly during the `lower` pass. This pass changes the Intermediate Representation to machine specific assembly.

at `writebarrier` (1 step before `lower`), instructions are still identical for both stuct sizes.

```
        v22 (7) = Phi <*SomeStruct> v14 v45
        v28 (7) = Phi <int> v16 v37
        v23 (7) = Phi <mem> v12 v27
        v37 (+7) = Add64 <int> v28 v36
        v39 (7) = Less64 <bool> v37 v8
        v25 (7) = VarDef <mem> {.autotmp_7} v23
        v26 (7) = LocalAddr <*SomeStruct> {.autotmp_7} v2 v25
        v27 (+7) = Move <mem> {SomeStruct} [72] v26 v22 v25  # <-- copy operation
```

as you can see there is  `Move` operation on v27.

However after the `lower` pass, the instructions diverge.

**with 9 int64 (72 bytes)**

```
        v22 (7) = Phi <*SomeStruct> v14 v45
        v28 (7) = Phi <int> v16 v37
        v23 (7) = Phi <mem> v12 v27
        v37 (+7) = ADDQconst <int> [1] v28
        v25 (7) = VarDef <mem> {.autotmp_7} v23
        v26 (7) = LEAQ <*SomeStruct> {.autotmp_7} v2
        v44 (7) = CMPQconst <flags> [1000000] v37
        v32 (+7) = LEAQ <*SomeStruct> {.autotmp_7} [8] v2
        v31 (+7) = ADDQconst <*SomeStruct> [8] v22
        v29 (+7) = MOVQload <uint64> v22 v25
        v24 (+7) = LEAQ <*SomeStruct> {.autotmp_7} [40] v2
        v15 (+7) = ADDQconst <*SomeStruct> [40] v22
        v46 (+7) = LEAQ <*SomeStruct> {.autotmp_7} [56] v2
        v35 (+7) = ADDQconst <*SomeStruct> [56] v22
        v21 (+7) = LEAQ <*SomeStruct> {.autotmp_7} [24] v2
        v17 (+7) = ADDQconst <*SomeStruct> [24] v22
        v39 (7) = SETL <bool> v44
        v42 (7) = TESTB <flags> v39 v39
        v30 (+7) = MOVQstore <mem> {.autotmp_7} v2 v29 v25
        v41 (+7) = MOVOload <int128> [8] v22 v30
        v20 (+7) = MOVOstore <mem> {.autotmp_7} [8] v2 v41 v30
        v34 (+7) = MOVOload <int128> [24] v22 v20
        v19 (+7) = MOVOstore <mem> {.autotmp_7} [24] v2 v34 v20
        v33 (+7) = MOVOload <int128> [40] v22 v19
        v38 (+7) = MOVOstore <mem> {.autotmp_7} [40] v2 v33 v19
        v47 (+7) = MOVOload <int128> [56] v22 v38
        v27 (+7) = MOVOstore <mem> {.autotmp_7} [56] v2 v47 v38
```

**with 10 int64 (80 bytes), it optimize MOVE using DUFFCOPY device**

```
    v22 (7) = Phi <*SomeStruct> v14 v45
    v28 (7) = Phi <int> v16 v37
    v23 (7) = Phi <mem> v12 v27
    v37 (+7) = ADDQconst <int> [1] v28
    v25 (7) = VarDef <mem> {.autotmp_7} v23
    v26 (7) = LEAQ <*SomeStruct> {.autotmp_7} v2
    v44 (7) = CMPQconst <flags> [1000000] v37
    v32 (+7) = LEAQ <*SomeStruct> {.autotmp_7} [8] v2
    v31 (+7) = ADDQconst <*SomeStruct> [8] v22
    v29 (+7) = MOVQload <uint64> v22 v25
    v39 (7) = SETL <bool> v44
    v42 (7) = TESTB <flags> v39 v39
    v30 (+7) = MOVQstore <mem> {.autotmp_7} v2 v29 v25
    v27 (+7) = DUFFCOPY <mem> [826] v32 v31 v30 # <---
```

This optimization is due to this [rule on rewriteAMD64.go](https://golang.org/src/cmd/compile/internal/ssa/rewriteAMD64.go#L54445)

```
match: (Move [s] dst src mem)
cond: s > 64 && s <= 16*64 && s%16 == 0 && !config.noDuffDevice
result: (DUFFCOPY [14*(64-s/16)] dst src mem)
```

at later stage (`elim unread autos`), SSA optimization can detect that the temp variable `autotmp_7` is not being used and can be removed. This is not the case with the larger struct with DUFFCOPY

I wrote it in a bit more details [here](https://labs.yulrizka.com/en/why-for-range-behave-differently-depending-on-the-size-of-the-element/)

Comment: I think you should accept your answer now as it's a great one and does perfectly answer the question, and consider copying the whole in here, since links (even your own) may eventually die. Also, I'd add that the fact it can't remove the `DUFFCOPY` is most likely because at a later stage it doesn't know it's "special" (or rather it's not special at all), so it can't know it doesn't have side-effects.